# Illegal string offset 'data' when i load the view

Tags: php, string, excel, codeigniter, offset

I've a problem about this illegal string offset

This is the controller named formlembur.php

```
      function download($lid)
      {
         $form_lembur = $this->form_lembur->read(array('lid' => $lid));
         $data['form_lembur'] = $form_lembur;
         //echo $data;die;(until this statement,it can load the data on database.
         //it actually showing the data.
         $this->load->view('exp-lembur', $data);
      }
```

This is the model named form_lembur.php

```
        public function read($where = FALSE)
        {
           if ($where === FALSE)
           {
                $query = $this->db->get('form_lembur');
                return $query->result_array();
           }

           $query = $this->db->get_where('form_lembur', $where);
           return $query->row_array();
        }
```

and this is the view before i download

```
<td> <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>formlembur/download/<?php echo $data->lid; ?>"><input type="submit" name="download" value="Download"></a></td>
```

and this is the view where i want the data viewed on excel named exp-lembur.php

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats xlsx");
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"Lembur.xls\"");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
  <meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<title>Reports</title>
<style>
    table.member
    {
          border:.5pt solid #000;
          border-collapse:collapse;
          font:14px tahoma;
          margin:0 auto;
          width:50%
    }
    table.member tr th{background-color:#999;border:.5pt solid #000}
    table.member tr.head th{color:#fff}
    table.member tr.data td{border:.5pt solid #000; vertical-align: top}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
      //print 'Generated On ' .date("j M y, g:i a",time()). '<br>';
  ?>
  <table class="member">
    <thead>
      <tr class="head">
        <th>Tanggal</th>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>Jabatan</th>
        <th>Jam Pulang</th>
        <th>Keperluan</th>
        <th>Instruktur</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Uang Lembur</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
      <tbody>
      <?php
          if (isset($form_lembur)){
              foreach($form_lembur as $k){

              print <<<h
              <tr class="data">
                    <td>{$k['date']}</td>
                    <td>{$k['nama']}</td>
                    <td>{$k['jabatan']}</td>
                    <td>{$k['jampulang']}</td>
                    <td>{$k['keperluan']}</td>
                    <td>{$k['instruktur']}</td>
                    <td>{$k['status']}</td>
                    <td>{$k['uanglembur']}</td>
               </tr>
               h;
               }
            }
        ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

but the problem is, it said that its an illegal string offset.
what is the problem ?
Please help me.

this is the error message ( showed on excel document because i try to download it into an excel document )

```
A PHP Error was encountered                         
Severity: Warning                           
Message: Illegal string offset 'date'                           
Filename: views/exp-lembur.php                          
Line Number: 50
```

Comment: copy paste the error message please

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered       
Severity: Warning       
Message: Illegal string offset 'date'       
Filename: views/exp-lembur.php       
Line Number: 50

Comment: @JonathandeM. that's the error message.
If i un-comment the echo $data;die; on controller.
It showing the data without any error.
But when i try to redirect it into the exp-lembur ( view )
it show that error message.

Comment: Include the structure of you're `array` `print_r` or `var_dump` it looks like it does not have the `date` on the array

Comment: Where is $form_lembur being set on that page? In formlembur.php, $form_lembur is used as a local variable in a function and as a class variable. Where is it defined that it would be accessible in exp-lembur.php, however?

Comment: Can you give me an example @tomexsans ?? I'm out of mind because of this. When i try to download all data ( using another syntax ). There's no problem on it. But if i try to download it by its id. This problem is appear.

Comment: After this:
    if (isset($form_lembur)){
do this:
print_r($form_lembur);

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox i think it's define in the controller.
    
            $this->load->view('exp-lembur', $form_lembur); 

So, i've to defined it on the exp-lembur.php ?

Comment: @ChicagoRedSox i found out the problem but i don't know for to fix it.
i make some change on view

<?php
  $form_lembur = $this->form_lembur->read(array('lid' => $lid));
  if (isset($form_lembur)){
    //print_r($form_lembur);die;(until this state, it still get the data)
    foreach($form_lembur as $data){
//print_r($data);die; ( but from this state, it only get the lid. And skip the other data in row.

Comment: Are you sure that you are selecting the date column in your query.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the model. It sometimes returns

```
$query->result_array()
```

and other time returns

```
$query->row_array()
```

depends on $where value. But result_array() gives this format:

```
$row[0]['date'];
```

when row_array() gives this format:

```
$row['date'];
```

That's why you have "Illegal string offset 'date'".

Comment: Thank bro. I found out the problem.
the problem is 
    
        foreach($form_lembur as $k)

If i try to print a data, i shouldn't try to loop it.
hahaa